# Did king David cause damage by viewing/ היזק ראיה?

Tags: halacha-theory, king-david, torts-damages

In 2 Shmuel 11 David views Batsheva bathing on her rooftop. Do any commentaries discuss if in so doing did David cause monetary damage under the principle of invasion of privacy (היזק ראייה)?

Comment: Maybe the laws of *hezek re'iyah* do not apply to a king because he is allowed to look at everything.

Comment: היזק ראייה is about being able to force your neighbor to modify his property to avoid invasions of your privacy.  There is no charge for היזק ראייה.

Comment: IIRC, היזק ראיה is not damage payable, but a means of obligating the Mazik to take measures to prevent. For example, if David's palace was built after Uriah's house, the latter could force David to build sufficient partitions so that Davis could not observe his roof in any way.

Answer (score 1):

David's seeing Batsheva bathing was accidental and unintentional - the story is detailed in [Sanhedrin 107a](http://David%27s%20seeing%20Batsheva%20bathing%20was%20completely%20accidental%20and%20unintentional.%20looking%20was%20unintentional.%20%5BSanhedrin%20107a%5D(https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.107a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)%20explains%20that%20his%20see):

> Bathsheba was shampooing her head behind a screen, which concealed
> her from sight. Satan came and appeared to David as a bird. David shot
> an arrow at the bird, the arrow broke the screen, Bathsheba was
> exposed, and David saw her.

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer doesn't argue for the opposite conclusion, David's residence was clearly situated in a way that allows for invasion of privacy and hence should be liable for היזק ראייה damages, whether or not the damages were caused intentionally

Comment: @riki - it's unclear from the question that you're asking about the design of David's palace to allow a view overlooking the city

Comment: How does this answer the question? Who cares if it was accidental or not?